# Excel Macro not work

Tags: excel, filtering, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that will filter on columns `E` and `F`. If both criteria are met, it will copy the entire row to a new sheet.

Here is what I have so far, but I can't get it to work...

```
Sub carving()

    '482
    SearchForString "482", "A01"
    SearchForString "482", "A02"
    SearchForString "482", "A03"
    SearchForString "482", "A04"


    '483
    SearchForString "483", "A01"
    SearchForString "483", "A02"
    SearchForString "483", "A03"
    SearchForString "483", "A04"

    '484
    SearchForString "484", "A01"
    SearchForString "484", "A02"
    SearchForString "484", "A03"
    SearchForString "484", "A04"


    '485
    SearchForString "485", "A01"
    SearchForString "485", "A02"
    SearchForString "485", "A03"
    SearchForString "485", "A04"

    '482E
    SearchForString "485", "A01"
    SearchForString "485", "A02"
    SearchForString "485", "A03"
    SearchForString "485", "A04"

    '482F
    SearchForString "485", "A01"
    SearchForString "485", "A02"
    SearchForString "485", "A03"
    SearchForString "485", "A04"

End Sub

Sub SearchForString(ColE, ColF)

    'Dim LSearchRow As Long
    Dim shtSearch As Worksheet
    Dim shtCopyTo As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range

    'LSearchRow = 2 'Start search in row 2

    Set shtSearch = Sheets("example")
    Set shtCopyTo = Sheets("test")

    Dim LSearchRow As Integer
    For LSearchRow = 2 To 30000
        If Len(shtSearch.Cells(LSearchRow, 1).Value) > 0 Then
            Set rw = shtSearch.Rows(LSearchRow)
            If rw.Cells(7).Value = ColE And rw.Cells(6).Value = ColF Then                                          
                rw.Copy shtCopyTo.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                'Exit Do '? you say there's only one result to find
            End If
        End If
    Next LSearchRow

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error message are you getting? You can isolate the line that is causing the problem by stepping through the code in the Debugger (use the F8 key while cursor is in code pane).

Comment: 'LSearchRow = 2 'Start search in row 2

Set shtSearch = Sheets("example")
Set shtCopyTo = Sheets("test")

Dim LSearchRow As Integer
For LSearchRow = 2 To 30000
    If Len(shtSearch.Cells(LSearchRow, 1).Value) > 0 Then
        Set rw = shtSearch.Rows(LSearchRow)
        If rw.Cells(5).Value = ColE And rw.Cells(6).Value = ColF Then

            rw.Copy shtCopyTo.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            'Exit Do '? you say there's only one result to find
        End If
    End If
Next LSearchRow

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick.

```
Sub MultiFilterAndCopy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Dim LastRow As Long
Dim PasteTo As Range

With Sheets("example").Range("E1:F1")
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "482", "483", "484", "485"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With



LastRow = Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Set PasteTo = Sheets("test").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Range("2:" & LastRow).Copy PasteTo

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

With this if you start with data as Below:

[image: Start]

Then Run just the filter portion of the Macro your Example sheet will look like below:

[image: Filtered]

And then when all is done your `Test` sheet will be as follows:

[image: Done]

If when you are finished you want the `example` sheet to return to its original state with all rows showing use the following modified macro:

```
Sub MultiFilterAndCopy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Dim LastRow As Long
Dim PasteTo As Range

With Sheets("example").Range("E1:F1")
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "482", "483", "484", "485"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With



LastRow = Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Set PasteTo = Sheets("test").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Range("2:" & LastRow).Copy PasteTo

Sheets("example").Range("E1:F1").AutoFilter

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: If you down vote my answer explain WHY as this is working answer.

Comment: I agree your answer is the best but my answer is not that bad if you see carefully.

Comment: The op used a loop initially and making it work was their original question not a complete rewrite.  Although I agree with your answer.

Comment: @glh I am unsure how my answer is childish, if you down voted my answer on reference of my comment to another question, then that is quite hypocritical. None the less I had no intentions of being childish or personal with Santosh, He stated in his answer that it contained NO loops, I was simply pointing out that it DID contain a loop, to make sure that the OA would not get confused on what loops are.I did also point out he made changes to the original code that had adverse affects that didn't take into account some of the OA's code.

Comment: @glh And his answer IS dangerous as if the OA used his code and executed the line `rngColE.EntireRow.Copy shtCopyTo.Cells(i, 1)` where I was dimmed as 1, the OA would loose ALL his preexisting data on the sheet, if he by accident ran that code on his actual data. Thus a completely acceptable downvote. Besisdes the fact he is leading future readers into a confusing situation when he IS using loops but stating he is not.

Comment: I agree with your point on overriding values but anyone running code on actual data without testing first is foolish. Also Santosh didn't say he wasn't using loops just that he wasn't looping each row and his use of the find command is not only common but in my view preferred.

Comment: @glh OK, and I simply stated he was still looping the funds, to which his reply was `My answer does not use ANY loops`. And I am unsure why you would prefer a 80% performance decrease. I'd use match or arrays over the find. You can reference [here](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/)

Comment: Also I find `AutoFilter` volitile as the copying of values whan nothing is found will be in most cases give the wrong result. In your case you will copy the headers and not the data not to mentioin if there is nothing in the last column A of the `test` sheet  you will also be overriding values, as I have just tested. Finding the last row with a value is better and escaping the copy is also preferred if nothing exists once you apply the `AutoFilter`.

Comment: Ahh yes but you missed the closer, that being there is a reason and a place to use each of them. In any case the OP has not marked either of your answers. ;)

Comment: The closer states Don’t use Range.Find unless you want to search a large number of columns for the same thing (you would have to do a Match for each column).the OA is using only 2 column's. And copying nothing will do not hung. And as A is being populated it will always have data and your statement is null.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code :

It uses the `Find` method of a range instead of looping thru each row which results in good performance. Also it copies all occurences of value.

You may refer this **[link](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)**

```
Dim i As Integer

Sub carving()
    i = 1
'482
    SearchForString "482", "A01"
    SearchForString "482", "A02"
    SearchForString "482", "A03"
    SearchForString "482", "A04"


    '483
    SearchForString "483", "A01"
    SearchForString "483", "A02"
    SearchForString "483", "A03"
    SearchForString "483", "A04"

    '484
    SearchForString "484", "A01"
    SearchForString "484", "A02"
    SearchForString "484", "A03"
    SearchForString "484", "A04"


    '485
    SearchForString "485", "A01"
    SearchForString "485", "A02"
    SearchForString "485", "A03"
    SearchForString "485", "A04"

    '482E
    SearchForString "485", "A01"
    SearchForString "485", "A02"
    SearchForString "485", "A03"
    SearchForString "485", "A04"

    '482F
    SearchForString "485", "A01"
    SearchForString "485", "A02"
    SearchForString "485", "A03"
    SearchForString "485", "A04"

End Sub

Sub SearchForString(ColE, ColF)

'Dim LSearchRow As Long
    Dim shtSearch As Worksheet, shtCopyTo As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range, rngColE As Range, rngColF As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, searchRngColE As Range
    Dim firstCell As String


    'LSearchRow = 2 'Start search in row 2

    Set shtSearch = Sheets("example")
    Set shtCopyTo = Sheets("test")

    lastRow = shtSearch.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow < 2 Then lastRow = 2

    Set searchRngColE = shtSearch.Range("E1:E" & lastRow)

    Set rngColE = searchRngColE.Find(What:=ColE, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

    If Not rngColE Is Nothing Then firstCell = rngColE.Address


    Do While Not rngColE Is Nothing

        If rngColE.Offset(0, 1) = ColF Then
            rngColE.EntireRow.Copy shtCopyTo.Cells(i, 1)
              i = i + 1
        End If


        Set rngColE = searchRngColE.FindNext(rngColE)

        If Not rngColE Is Nothing Then
            If rngColE.Address = firstCell Then Exit Do
        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your still looping the finds and looping all the possible matches. On top of that you are not coping the rows to the end of the `test` sheet, instead from the top, overwriting what would already be there. My answer does not use ANY loops, and copies everything to the row below the last non blank row on the `test` sheet.

Comment: @user2140261  `My answer does not use ANY loops, and copies everything to the row`  why did you comment here? Do you think you are smart ?

Comment: A Do While is a Loop. [Learn More Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx) , Plus the entire Carving Sub is one big manual loop. And I comment to help teach the Asker.

Comment: @user2140261 Dont you think OP can adjust that much `Offset(1, 0)` or you think you are the only smart person ?

Comment: Listen, I am sorry I hurt your feelings and your ego by pointing out your lie. I was simply trying to help the OP, understand what he was looking at. And if you down voted my answer please leave a comment on why.

Comment: And just so we are clear on the facts. looping your macro 100 times takes 14.625. While looping mine 100 times takes 8.094 seconds. Thats about 80% faster.

Comment: @user2140261 can you also calculate how much time it would take as per OP post and how much improvement did my code made to it